# Installing Tensorflow on macOS thru native pip

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

Using a :

- macOS High Sierra version 10.13.5
- python version is 2.7.10

I am trying to install tensorflow on my macOS through native pip but i encountered an issue when trying to validate my installation. I am following the installation instructions from this website :

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#top_of_page

The issue occurs when I run the following short tensorflow program after I invoke python from it's shell

```
# Python
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

but I get in return :

```
... import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
>>> sess = tf.Session()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
```

I used the following links to see if i can find the answer

[ImportError: No module named tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244198/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5478

[ImportError: No module named tensorflow - Can't install Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472144/importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow-cant-install-tensorflow)

Also during the installation of *native pip* I did *sudo* install tornado & nose. The versions are Tornado 5.1 & nose 1.3.7

Comment: What version of python do you have? I imagine 2.7 on your Mac? I’d suggest using the virtual environment installation with easy_install, have you tried that way?

Comment: I resolved the issue by uninstalling python 3.7 and installing 3.6.6. Doing so resolved my issue and I was able validate my installation. Thank you